# Can't unlock bootloader Moto G5 XT1672

Tags: bootloader, motorola, motorola-moto-g5

I'm trying to unlock the bootloader on my Moto G5, the adb commands works, but I can't find my device in the command prompt when it is in fastboot mode.

I was following the instructions on [this](https://forum.xda-developers.com/g5-plus/how-to/unlock-bootloader-lenovo-motorola-moto-t3581133) tutorial, but when running the `adb device` command to get my serial number, the PC can't find the device. I checked the USB cable and the connection between the device and the computer and everything is ok.

To enter the fastboot mode I was using the `adb reboot bootloader`command on Windows.

Android 8.1.0
Security patch: October 1, 2018

Comment: You don't have the right drivers for fastboot mode, look in your Window's Device Manager when the phone is connected in Fastboot mode, you should see either an Unknown Device or something similar, change the driver to the generic ones that come with ADB. Or use Linux, which doesn't require any drivers when communicating with an Android device.

Comment: I am a bit confused on what was where. I do not want to assume anything so could you please clarify one thing. Where are you throwing the command `adb devices`?? Are you in the Command prompt when you are in Fastboot/Bootloader mode?? Because it will not work. Adb protocol is used within a booted System and Recovery and not within the Bootloader. To communicate with the Bootloader/fastboot mode you need to use the Fastboot protocol. Try throwing this command: `fastboot devices` see if that yields any results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As acejavelin said, I was missing the fastboot driver, for some reason it wasn't finding my phone. Installing the right driver solved the problem.